# Wrong language fonts at multi language app

Tags: android, fonts, multilingual

i'm trying to make a multilanguage app, English and Greek.
All i want is 2 buttons at the first screen that u will choose language and then all the other app will bve at that language. I have make a simple test project with 2 buttons and a paragraph, when u push the english button the text will be english, when u push the greek button the text will be greek.
My code

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page2);

    Button english = (Button) findViewById(R.id.english);
    english.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Locale locale = new Locale("en_UK"); 
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;

            getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

    });
    Button greek = (Button) findViewById(R.id.greek);
    greek.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Locale locale = new Locale("el_GR"); 
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;

            getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

    });



}
```

the strings.xml with the english paragraph is at the original res/values folder 
and the strings.xml with the greek language is in res/values-el

here is 3 screenshots from the test app
here is some screenshots:

[image: http://s18.postimg.org/dw0dvdsr9/Screenshot_2013_09_04_15_27_58.png]

[image: http://s18.postimg.org/6u2g96p5h/Screenshot_2013_09_04_15_28_08.png]

[image: http://s18.postimg.org/7kv6eyrit/Screenshot_2013_09_04_15_28_14.png]

the one with the non letters things is the greek paragraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that your phone doesnot supports unicode characters for greek,
there are two solutions,

1)It means that fonts your device uses do not support greek characters (hence `unknown unicode`). You need to find better font and use it in your application (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html docs)

2)get online unicode converter or google translator for english to greek and copy the words to your strings.xml